# Как ограничить время выполнения ожидания ответа?

Tags: ajax, php

Бодрого всем дня!

```
//сей код есть AJAX
function update(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            type:"POST",
            cache:true,
            data: "id="+$(this).attr("value"),
            success: function(html){
                $("#category_tray_one").html(html);
                update();
            }
        })
}
```

Вот у меня есть success, но дело в том, что иногда данные попадают туда за 5 сек., а иногда за 55 сек., что плохо. Можно ли как-то ограничить время выполнения ожидания ответа? Охота, если ответа нет, скажем, 20 сек. - или запрос к другой странице, или заранее заготовленную переменную подставить для возврата. Может кто помочь?

p.s. Первая ассоциация - проверка времени в цикле, но цикла, по сути, нет. (

Comment: у jQuery.ajax есть параметр timeout, документация тут http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: все ответы и примеры можно найти в гугле https://www.google.ru/#q=jquery+ajax+timeout